# When I am trying to create new Project from File->New_>Maven Project, I obtain error:

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

When I am trying to create new Project from File->New_>Maven Project, I obtain error:

> Could not resolve archetype
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the
>   configured repositories. Could not resolve artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 Failure to
>   transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
>   from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository,  resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):  repo.maven.apache.org
>   Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository,  resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

1. close your eclipse
2. go to C:\Users\yourname\ and delete .m2 folder
3. open eclipse and Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings
4. Enter the Maven installed directory in Global settings
5. Restart the eclipse
6. Try to create project again and make sure you have internet connectivity without any firewall protected.

Comment: do not delete the entire .m2, just .m2/repository. Keep the settings.xml

Comment: how to find out Maven installed directory @Ranjith sekar

Answer (score 0):

> [...] was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try `mvn clean install -U` to force the update. In Eclipse, that would be the *Update Maven projects on startup* in the global Maven settings.

If that still fails you, you could manually delete your local maven folder, by default the *user-folder/.m2/repository*, that should force a full refetch